# Cover Photo Preview

Tags: facebook, photo, facebook-timeline

We have an app that adds a photo to a users' album, then directs them to https://www.facebook.com/[profile_id]?preview_cover=[image_id] so they can save it as their cover photo.

It has been working for months, but as of today, that link ends up with a white box and no photo.

Does anyone know if Facebook changed this functionality?   I couldn't find anything about it in their documentation.